# Exception while reading image ==java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null

Tags: java, image, iterator, image-formats

I am reading a image and want to get the image format.

```
private static String getFormatName(Object o) {
try {
    // Create an image input stream on the image
    ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(o);

    // Find all image readers that recognize the image format
    Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        // No readers found
        return null;
    }

    // Use the first reader
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader)iter.next();

    String name = reader.getFormatName();
    iis.close();
    return name;
} catch (IOException e) {
}
// The image could not be read
return null;
```

}

when I execute it I am getting the following exception,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
```

Comment: It seems like image is not found (image=null), probably path is wrong? Did you check the stack trace?

Comment: What are you passing in for the Object and on what line is the IllegalArgumentException thrown? Is it thrown by ImageIO.createImageInputStream?

Comment: @VICKY-TSC - out of curiosity, why did you unmark my answer as the correct one? I believe you do need all 4 lines of code I listed for this to work. ??? - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Closing the stream, before the reader gets the chance to read the format..

So the **sequence of statements** are:

```
reader.getFormatName();
iis.close();
return name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated: You also need to call setInput()

You can't close the stream. When you do how is the reader going to read the image? Do the following:

```
reader.setInput(iis);
String name = reader.getFormatName();
iis.close();
return name;
```

Comment: @VICKY-TSC - I added an additional line of code to make it work (sorry, forgot it the first time).